# pos for.net in windows 7 vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, barcode, barcode-scanner, motorola

I am using microsoft POS for .net dll  and  I am converting this part to vb.net from a HOL sample barcode reading tutorial written in c# [found here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34473/Controlling-a-Barcode-Reader-with-POS-for-NET?fid=1537938&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&spc=Relaxed&fr=1#xx0xx).

EDIT:The device list shows and popup window shows (the activate button is pressed and scanner input is tested)but the txteventhistory is not update even when scanner emulator is used and i suspect the said part is the culprit. thank you for the response

```
{
        Action<string> updateEventHistoryAction = new Action<string>(p => { txtEventHistory.Text = p; });
        txtEventHistory.Invoke(updateEventHistoryAction, newEvent);
    }
```

from this

```
void activeScanner_DataEvent(object sender, DataEventArgs e)
{
UpdateEventHistory("Data Event");
ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
try
{
    // Display the ASCII encoded label text
    string data = encoder.GetString(activeScanner.ScanDataLabel);
    Action<string> updateScanDataLabelAction = new Action<string>(p => {txtScanDataLabel.Text = p;});
    txtScanDataLabel.Invoke(updateScanDataLabelAction, data);

    // Display the encoding type
    string dataType = activeScanner.ScanDataType.ToString();
    Action<string> updateScanDataTypeLabelAction = new Action<string>(p => { txtScanDataType.Text = p; });
    txtScanDataType.Invoke(updateScanDataTypeLabelAction, dataType);

    // re-enable the data event for subsequent scans
    activeScanner.DataEventEnabled = true;
}
catch (PosControlException)
{
    // Log any errors
    UpdateEventHistory("DataEvent Operation Failed");
}
}
```

the conversion tool in #develop yielded the one below but i don't think it's correct

```
Dim updateScanDataLabelAction As New Action(Of String)(function (p)
                    txtScanDataLabel.Text = p
end function)
txtEventHistory.Invoke(updateEventHistoryAction, newEvent)
```

I tried converting it to but not quite there i think, though it

```
Private Sub activeScanner_DataEvent(sender As Object, e As DataEventArgs)
    UpdateEventHistory("Data Event")
       Dim encoder As New ASCIIEncoding()
          Try
        ' Display the ASCII encoded label text
        Dim data As String = encoder.GetString(activeScanner.ScanDataLabel)
            Dim updateScanDataLabelAction append As New Action(Of String))
               txtEventHistory.Invoke(updateEventHistoryAction, newEvent)
               txtScanDataType.Invoke(updateScanDataTypeLabelAction, dataType)

        ' re-enable the data event for subsequent scans
        activeScanner.DataEventEnabled = True
    Catch generatedExceptionName As PosControlException
            ' Log any errors
            UpdateEventHistory("DataEvent Operation Failed")
      End Try
    End Sub

Private Sub p(ByVal text As String)
            txtScanDataType.Text = text
    End Sub
```

here is the whole code

```
Imports Microsoft.PointOfService
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace POS
    Partial Public Class ScannerLab
        Inherits Form
        Private explorer As PosExplorer
        Private scannerList As DeviceCollection
        Private scannerList1 As DeviceCollection
        Private activeScanner As Scanner

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ScannerLab_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)handles mybase.load
        explorer = New PosExplorer()

        scannerList1 = explorer.GetDevices()
        bsdevices.DataSource = scannerList1
        cboDevices.DisplayMember = scannerList1.ToString()

        scannerList = explorer.GetDevices(DeviceType.Scanner)
        devicesBindingSource.DataSource = scannerList
        lstDevices.DisplayMember = scannerList.ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnActivateDevice_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) handles btnActivateDevice.Click
        If lstDevices.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            ActivateScanner(DirectCast(lstDevices.SelectedItem, DeviceInfo))
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub reportFailure()
        Throw New Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ActivateScanner(ByVal selectedScanner As DeviceInfo) 
        'Verifify that the selectedScanner is not null
        ' and that it is not the same scanner already selected
        If selectedScanner IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not selectedScanner.IsDeviceInfoOf(activeScanner) Then
            ' Configure the new scanner
            DeactivateScanner()

            ' Activate the new scanner
            UpdateEventHistory(String.Format("Activate Scanner: {0}", selectedScanner.ServiceObjectName))
            Try
                activeScanner = DirectCast(explorer.CreateInstance(selectedScanner), Scanner)
                activeScanner.Open()
                activeScanner.Claim(1000)
                activeScanner.DeviceEnabled = True
                AddHandler activeScanner.DataEvent, AddressOf activeScanner_DataEvent
                AddHandler activeScanner.ErrorEvent, AddressOf activeScanner_ErrorEvent
                activeScanner.DecodeData = True
                activeScanner.DataEventEnabled = True
            Catch generatedExceptionName As PosControlException
                ' Log error and set the active scanner to none
                UpdateEventHistory(String.Format("Activation Failed: {0}", selectedScanner.ServiceObjectName))
                activeScanner = Nothing
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DeactivateScanner()
        If activeScanner IsNot Nothing Then
            ' We have an active scanner, lets log that we are
            ' about to close it.
            UpdateEventHistory("Deactivate Current Scanner")

            Try
                ' Close the active scanner
                activeScanner.Close()
            Catch generatedExceptionName As PosControlException
                ' Log any error that happens
                UpdateEventHistory("Close Failed")
            Finally
                ' Don't forget to set activeScanner to null to
                ' indicate that we no longer have an active
                ' scanner configured.
                activeScanner = Nothing
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub activeScanner_DataEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataEventArgs)
        UpdateEventHistory("Data Event")
        Dim encoder As New ASCIIEncoding()

        Try
            ' Display the ASCII encoded label text
            Dim data As String = encoder.GetString(activeScanner.ScanDataLabel)
            Dim updateScanDataLabelAction As New Action(Of String)(AddressOf p)
            txtScanDataLabel.Invoke(updateScanDataLabelAction, data)

            ' Display the encoding type
            Dim dataType As String = activeScanner.ScanDataType.ToString()
            Dim updateScanDataTypeLabelAction As New Action(Of String)(AddressOf p)

            txtScanDataType.Invoke(updateScanDataTypeLabelAction, dataType)

            ' re-enable the data event for subsequent scans
            activeScanner.DataEventEnabled = True
        Catch generatedExceptionName As PosControlException
            ' Log any errors
            UpdateEventHistory("DataEvent Operation Failed")
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub p(ByVal text As String)
        txtScanDataType.Text = text

    End Sub
    Private Sub q(ByVal text As String)
        txtScanDataType.Text = text

    End Sub
    Private Sub UpdateEventHistory(ByVal newEvent As String)
        If txtEventHistory.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim updateEventHistoryAction As New Action(Of String)(AddressOf q)


            txtEventHistory.Invoke(updateEventHistoryAction, newEvent)
        Else
            txtEventHistory.Text = (Convert.ToString(newEvent) & System.Environment.NewLine) + txtEventHistory.Text
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub activeScanner_ErrorEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DeviceErrorEventArgs)
        UpdateEventHistory("Error Event")

        Try

            ' re-enable the data event for subsequent scans

            activeScanner.DataEventEnabled = True

        Catch generatedExceptionName As PosControlException
            ' Log any errors
            UpdateEventHistory("ErrorEvent Operation Failed")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

EDIT: updated the code

Comment: Why do you think that the problem is with the method "activeScanner_DataEvent"? According to your error description, the problem should rather be related to the method "ScannerLab_Load".

Comment: yes you are correct. the combo box and listview have been assigned a datasource like the one in c# but still no go

Comment: Compare how you handle "scannerList" and "lstDevices" in your ScannerLab_Load method with the code snippets in Exercise 2, Step 8. in the tutorial you linked.

Comment: i changed scannerlist to arraylist and editted it but no change 'code'scannerList = New ArrayList(explorer.GetDevices("Scanner"))
            devicesBindingSource.DataSource = scannerList
            lstDevices.DataSource = devicesBindingSource
            lstDevices.DisplayMember = "ServiceObjectName" 'code'

Comment: Okay, it's time for you to use the debugger. Set a break point at the line "scannerList = New ArrayList(explorer.GetDevices("Scanner"));" and step through the code. Continuously monitor the content of the scannerList. Does the scannerList contain objects, or is it empty? If it contains objects, do they have a public property named "ServiceObjectName", and if so, what is its value? Does the scannerList (and the devicesBindingSource, respectively) still contain the objects when assigned to lstDevices? Is the devicesBindingSource object used somewhere else outside of the method ScannerLab_Load()?

Comment: Just some more detail: explorer.GetDevices() returns a collection of DeviceInfo objects, which should have a ServiceObjectName property.

Comment: thank you for the tip. I managed to make it work by adding handles mybase.load at Private Sub ScannerLab_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)handles mybase.load. now for the main part. I do not have the hardware yet but I think this code has issues when running at windows 7 and i do not know if the issues are resolved especially since I switched to vb, which is why I am asking if that code block is translated correctly. thank you again